# How to use Laravel models in ordinary PHP files

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel website; within this I have an ordinary PHP file which responds to a webhook. 
How can I use Laravel models (eg \App\User) in this PHP file?

Thanks

Comment: Does it still run through your Controller?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you use with blade. But just, you can't use blate curly braces `{{}}`. So you will have to echo everythig. If you pass a `$user` from the controller, then you can do

```
<?php echo $user->email; ?>
```

If you want to access models directly from the file without passing from another file then give it a namespace and make use of `use`.

`myfile.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Wherever\You\Want;
use App\User;
...
```

Comment: Thanks Eddy. This PHP file is just within my public directory. It's just trying to edit the database, i.e. something like \App\User::where('user_type','admin')->update(['updated_at'=>\Carbon\Carbon::now()]);

In this case what should the namespace be? And what else do I need to include? Thanks!

Comment: Im sort of curious as to what that file is doing that CANNOT be done within a controller. Inside of your composer.json, there is like with `"psr-4"`. That line basically tells Laravel where to load classes. So putting some logic inside of public, is litteraly out of Laravel. Maybe it's possible, but I recommend you to copy that file content into a Helper maybe and call it where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model in your php file like this.

> use App\Models\User;

and call the methods of the model by creating instance of this model.

> $user = new User;